# Gigabyte On/Off charge. How to get it to work?

Tags: usb, motherboard, charging

I have [GA-H81M-S1 (rev. 2.0)](http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4833#ov) motherboard. According to its [specification](http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4833#sp) it supports Gigabyte On/Off charge.

I keep my phone(Redmi Note 3) connected to my pc with its screen awake all the time and due to low current instead of charging its discharge my phone(slowly)

So i wanted to use [Gigabyte On/Off charge technology](http://www.gigabyte.in/MicroSite/185/on-off-charge.htm) . I installed On/off charge driver and app center as mentioned in the [downloads](http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4833#utility). But none of the usb ports provide enough current to charge my phone.

According to [Gigabyte On/Off charge technology](http://www.gigabyte.in/MicroSite/185/on-off-charge.htm). I need to connect front usb panel to a red/white port specifically designed for On/off charge.

[image]

But my motherboard doesn't have those red/white ports.

I have two ports available to plug my front usb port. None of them is red/whtie port as in above image.

[image]

How can i use on/off charge exactly without those port?

Comment: **But none of the usb ports provide enough current to charge my phone.**  How did you determine this?  What PSU do you have, this feature is limited to the 5V, supplied by your PSU.  To answer your question all your USB ports support this feature.  The way you can determine that is, connect your phone to your computer, then shut it down.  Your phone will continue to charge.

Comment: I think he is saying that the current is too low to keep up with the discharge while plugged in and always on. I think the "basic standard" for USB 3.0 ports is 900mA. So GB "3x" may mean 1.5 amps (3xusb2.0) or 2.7 amps (3xUSB3). The phone quoted appears to draw a max of about 1.4 Amps when charging. ( http://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-note-2/general/xiaomi-redmi-note-2-charging-analysis-t3187536/post62528740#post62528740 )

Comment: The specs page shows it has it, under unique features...http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4833#sp

Comment: I have contacted gigabyte support and they said all USB ports in this motherboard support on/off charge.

Comment: @Ramhound No my phone is not charging after shutting down my PC.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Gigabyte On/Off charge blurb, it will ONLY charge Apple products.

> GIGABYTE's latest motherboards are equipped with ON/OFF Charge
>   technology which allows you not only to charge your iPhone, iPad or
>   iPod Touch, but it allows you to Quick Charge it. As an added bonus,
>   it can even be charged when your PC is turned off, so even if you
>   forget to plug it into your charger after you've synced up your music,
>   it will be fully charged when you need it.

http://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/185/on-off-charge.htm

Comment: I believe this is correct. I've tried charging my HTC phone through various USB ports on my PC, none provide enough current to make my phone happy. I wish Gigabyte had been more upfront that this is an Apple-only feature.